# Identifying processes with Auto login\Cached domain username and passwords

Tags: windows-xp

After changing my domain password, my domain account is getting constantly getting locked out. On verifying the event log on the server, "Failure Audits" were found which was comming from my workstation only.

I tried clearing the browser password cache and password cache from control panel-> user accounts. Is there any way to identify which process is making requests with the old domain password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look for services that may be configured to run under your user account.

Comment: Joeqwerty, thanks for the suggestion. Finally I found the culprit.

Comment: Glad to help and glad you found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the culprit which was making requests with my old password. Here's what I did to get zero in in the process.

1. Installed ZoneAlarm.
2. Enabled the option "Request permission for process when connecting internet".
3. Allowed programs one after another and finally zeroed in on Skype.

In Skype "Enable proxy Authentication" was checked and my old password was set, after changing this the account lockout issue got resolved.